# Custom UIButton throw multiple design errors

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, ibdesignable

I'm dealing with an XCode error that I don't understand, I've been looking for solutions for days now, and Pods update, XCode restart or anything else doesn't seem to throw the problem away ...

I have a custom class which extends from UIButton :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//@IBDesignable  <-- COMMENTED BUT SAME ERRORS ... 
class CustomCardButton: UIButton {

    var nibName = "CustomCardButton"

    @IBOutlet weak var btnImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLabel: UILabel!

    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        get {
            return btnImageView.image
        } set(image) {
            btnImageView.image = image
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var label: String? {
        get {
            return btnLabel.text
        } set(label) {
            btnLabel.text = label
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
        btnImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 60/2
        btnImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 5/255,
                                                 green: 66/255, blue: 38/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        btnImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        btnLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)
        btnImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        btnLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIButton {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIButton
        return view
    }   
}
```

It's a well copy-pasted code from SO : [Swift, Custom UIButton does not work when click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317796/swift-custom-uibutton-does-not-work-when-click)

And my xib file looks like this :

[image]

I kept it simple for now, yesterday I tried it with a more complicated (Yeah 2 labels and an imageview Woooh, complicated for xcode ... ) and I had the same error ..

The errors are :

Pre-compilation :

[image]

After app launch it crashes and I have this :

30 `let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIButton`
**Thread 1 : EXC_BAD ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x16fc5bfd0)**

31 `let view = loadViewFromNib()`
**Thread 1 : EXC_BAD ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x16fc5bfd0)**

32 `setup()`
**Thread 1 : EXC_BAD ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x16fc5bfd0)**

And I got those errors from 31 to 2840 ...

I saw it was an XCode bug, and we cannot do anything about that, but I really need a Custom button with 2 labels and an ImageVIew ...

Comment: try by removing @IBDesignable

Comment: Are you sure `instantiateWithOwner` is returning an array?

Comment: I added this : `print("BEFORE VIEW ")
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIButton
        print("VIEW : \(view)" )` And I have a loop of "BEFORE VIEW", then it throw an excpetion ..

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz In your nib file, what is the class of your view? Sounds like maybe it's your custom class "CustomCardButton", It will crash by infinite loop, you need the file manager to be your custom class.

Comment: Its class is CustomCardButton, otherwise I would not be able to add IBOutlet to the class

Comment: @NicolasCharvoz this is the reason you have the crash, you need your file owner (not manager as I said before :) to be your class. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `UIView's` class to be just `UIView`, and not your custom class directly, your custom class is the `File's owner` in this case.

You instantiate this view when it loads, so if the custom class will be your class, it will run over and over and over again...

**The nib:** 
Make a `UIView` with `UIButton` as sub view (If your view will be some UIView that you change it's class to be `UIButton`, your `IBActions` wont work, so better to work with `UIButton` as sub view)

[image]

And your `File's owner` is your custom class: 
[image]

Now you can ctrl-drag `IBOutlets` to you `File's owner`, just ctrl drag form the `File's owner` to the desired view:

[image] [image]

You can do the same with `IBActions` to the button

**Your code will change a bit:**

The custom class as been said is *`UIView`*:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomCardButton: UIView
```

And the `loadViewFromNib` method, will return `UIView`, and not `UIButton`:

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}
```

That's it, you should see your `IBDesignable` in your storyBoard:

[image]

With `IBInspectables`:

[image]